# Is there a possibility to rewrite array into the new by using map(), with specific elements

Tags: javascript

Need to write only odd numbers into new array by using map(). but get odd numbers combined with 'true'

Tried to use:

```
if (value % 2 != 0) {

            return value;
        }
```

but get output: 5,,15,,31,,165,

```
var arrayOfNumbers = [5, 8, 15, 22, 31, 54, 165, 852];
var arrayOfOddNumbers;

print("Array of numbers: " + arrayOfNumbers);


arrayOfOddNumbers = arrayOfNumbers.map(
    function (value, index) {
        // I tried to use delete
        return value % 2 != 0 ? value : delete arrayOfNumbers[value];


    });



print("Array of odd numbers: " + arrayOfOddNumbers);
```

expected to get: 5,15,31,165; 
but get: 5,true,15,true,31,true,165,true

Comment: Why not `.filter()`?

Comment: You get `true` because you return the result of `delete arrayOfNumbers[value]` succesfully deletes the property. You have to `.filter(Boolean)` after the map to remove the true/false values. But then you might as well just use `.filter()` to begin with instead of `.map()` as described in the answers. Keep in mind that by using `delete arrayOfNumbers[x]`, you change the original arrayOfNumbers and you use an object operator ( delete ) on an array, so both are not adviced.

Comment: @Shilly, thank's for deeper explanation of mistake

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to `map` but to [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
arrayOfOddNumbers = arrayOfNumbers.filter(v => v%2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use forEach and push item to your result

```
var arrayOfNumbers = [5, 8, 15, 22, 31, 54, 165, 852];
    var arrayOfOddNumbers = [];
    arrayOfNumbers.forEach(c=> { if(c%2 != 0) arrayOfOddNumbers.push(c)});
```

```js
var arrayOfNumbers = [5, 8, 15, 22, 31, 54, 165, 852];
var arrayOfOddNumbers = [];
arrayOfNumbers.forEach(c=> { if(c%2 != 0) arrayOfOddNumbers.push(c)});
console.log(arrayOfOddNumbers)
```

Comment: `filter()` is way more natural (and compact) way to do that, don't you think?

Comment: yes, may OP is newbie, I want to provide an option for him